# Converse to Composition of Finite Homomorphisms is Finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

Let $A,B,C$ be rings. I know if $A \to B \to C$ where $A \to B$ and $B \to C$ are finite, then $A \to C$ is finite (i.e. as modules). My question is, if we know $A \to C$ is finite, does it follow that $A \to B$ or $B \to C$ is finite. Specifically, what if in this case $A$ is Noetherian and $B = A[x]$ is also Noetherian by Hilbert's basis theorem?

Comment: Certainly, it seems to me that $B \to C$ must be finite: by hypothesis, there exist finitely many $c_{1},  \ldots, c_{n} \in C$ such that we can express for any $c \in C$, there exist $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in A$ such that $a_{1}c_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}c_{n}$. But the $A$-module structure on $C$ comes from the map $A \to C$, which factors through the map $A \to B$, so if $c = a_{1}c_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}c_{n}$, then letting $b_{i}$ be the image of $a_{i}$ under the map $A \to B$, then we must have $c = b_{1}c_{1}+\cdots + b_{n}c_{n}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems I'm garbling a lot of my comments with edits lately. The above should read: "...such that for any $c \in C$, there exist $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in A$ such that $c = a_{1}c_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}c_{n}$."